# use regex and awk/sed to remove rows with columns having 4 or more repeated characters

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have data where one of the columns which is a string has repeated characters and I want to remove if that column has 4 consecutive repeated characters or more. "ww wwww", "((((", "))))", "a bbbb" and I want to remove all such rows with 4 or more repeated characters 
I was trying the variant of `awk -F $'\t' '$1 ~ ([a-z])\1{3}| (/()\1{3} {print $0}' input.txt`
but that does not work.

```
apps    -1  qqqq
apps    -1  ((( ((((
apps    -1  spotify
apps    -1  side
apps    -1  pp
```

and I want the output to be

```
apps    -1  spotify
apps    -1  side
apps    -1  pp
```

Comment: Why is `pp` allowed but `qqqq` isn't?

Comment: Sorry I wanted 4 or more repeated characters

Comment: So you're looking to remove patterns that match `(.){4,}$`?

Comment: Yes I  was looking for removing all instance of four or more repeated characters. "aaaa" "qqqqq" etc

Comment: Try `(.)\1{3,}`

Answer (score 2):

If the first two columns are always what you show in the example, you could use this:

```
 grep -vE '([[:graph:]])\1\1\1' input.txt
```

This excludes any line that has a graphical character four times in a row. `(.)\1\1\1` doesn't work because it matches four spaces.

Alternatively, one character shorter:

```
 grep -vE '([[:graph:]])\1{3}' input.txt
```

Comment: +1 for using the right tool. `grep` is perfectly capable of handling this request - no need for `sed`, `awk`, `perl` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu sed` command should work:

```
sed -E '/([^[:blank:]])\1{3}/d' file
```

```
apps    -1  spotify
apps    -1  side
apps    -1  pp
```

or else, you may use command line `perl` also:

```
perl -ne 'print if $_ !~ /(\S)\1{3}/' file
```

```
apps    -1  spotify
apps    -1  side
apps    -1  pp
```